# How to get a set of rows of a dataframe that the rownames match a given list?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that is structured as follows, where each column is a feature (a,b,c,d..) of a given entry (the entries being TCxxx). The data frame contains nearly 3000 rows and 9000 columns.

```
      a b c e f g h
TC001 1 5 2 3 2 2 2
TC002 2 9 2 3 5 3 4
TC003 3 6 6 1 4 7 7
```

I also have a text file that each line is an identifier:

```
TC005
TC012
TC037
```

How to turn this text file into a list of identifiers, then create a set from the data frame containing only the rows that match the identifier of the text file?

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` or `database` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_indexes <- scan(<path/to/text/file>)

my_data_frame[my_indexes,]
```

Comment: Thanks! It didn't work straight ahead, but it gave me ideas, scan() couldn't turn the text file into a list so i used read.table() instead then passed it as.list()